# change variable value once a button has been clicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is to be able to change the value of val once btn-here has been clicked. I have the following code but it is not working. what am I missing?

```
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn-here');
    var val = document.getElementById('text-here').value;
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var val = '100';
    });
```

Comment: val inside the addEventListener is not the same val that are outside.
you just create another var that have the some name as the old one.
replace var val = '100'; by val = '100';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code snippet should be helpful in clarifying why the code in the question does not achieve it's expected objective as well as provide an alternative that works.

**Code Snippet**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn-here');
// in below, one is directly accessing the "value" 
var val = document.getElementById('text-here').value;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // var val = '100';  // even if one removes "var", the value will still 
  val = '100';      // not be assigned to element "text-here"
  console.log('val is now ', val);
  console.log('but, "text-here" element value remains: ', document.getElementById('text-here').value);
});

// below is one way to achieve the expected objective
// it uses no variables & directly manipulates the HTML elements
document.getElementById("btn-here-works").addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("text-here").value = '100';
});

// below is another alternative which uses variables
// which resembles closely what the OP has described in their question
// declare btn to hold the element with id "btn-here"
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn-here2');

// declare userInput to hold "text-here" (which is <input />)
const userInput = document.getElementById('text-here2');

// add click event listner where userInput.value is assigned a value 100
btn2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  userInput.value = '100';
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-here">button</button>
<input id="text-here" />
<button id="btn-here-works">button works</button>
<br/><br/>

<button id="btn-here2">button-2</button>
<input id="text-here2" />
```

**Explanation**

- It is my understanding that `var val = document.getElementById('text-here').value;` provides a read-only access to the `value` prop of the HTML-element
- Hence when assigning `100` to `val`, the HTML-element remains unaffected
- Modifying `var val = '100';` to `val = 100` does not achieve what OP expects
- Instead, if one accesses the HTML-element (& not it's `value` prop) by using a variable such as `userInput`
- Then, one is able to assign a value to `userInput.value` which then changes the `value` prop of the HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the value of your variable, you don't need to declare that again. So your code will look something like:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn-here');
var val = document.getElementById('text-here').value;
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   val = '100';
});
```